# ag-grid React refreshCells is not affected by state changes

Tags: ag-grid

my react grid has a some row values that depends on state (Actually has a slider column).

But i need to show new slider value after state changed by slider. I did it by call `redrawRows()` because `refreshCells()` is not changing cell value as state. `refreshcells` is does nothing into slider.

`redrawRows` working good but losing mousedown event on slider. i changing slider value with mouse and slider's mousedown handling is lost after `redrawRows`. I must re press mouse button on every slider value change

Why `refreshCells` does not update cell value?

Answer (score 0):

For the `refreshCells` to work, your slider cell renderer component should implement `refresh()` method.
As per the docs -

> To handle refresh, implement logic inside the refresh() method inside
>   your component and return true. If you do not want to handle refresh,
>   just return false from the refresh method (which will tell the grid
>   you do not handle refresh and your component will be destroyed and
>   recreated if the underlying data changes).
>
> Refresh Cells: api.refreshCells(cellRefreshParams) - Gets the grid to
>   refresh all cells. Change detection will be used to refresh only cells
>   who's display cell values are out of sync with the actual value. If
>   using a cellRenderer with a refresh method, the refresh method will
>   get called.

In your case, it may be possible that the refresh method is not being called.
Please read more on cell renderer component life cycle [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component-lifecycle)